# JOIN to read first table and get possible relationship in the second table

Tags: mysql, join, relational-theory

Consider a main table as

```
CREATE TABLE groups
(
group_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
group_title varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY(group_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

and a second table for relationship as

```
CREATE TABLE group_members
(
relation_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
group_id int(11),
user_id int(11),
FOREIGN KEY(group_id) REFERENCES groups(group_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(relationsh_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

How to get a full list of all `groups` with an additional column indicating that if a given user is member of each group or not. This means that we will have a `WHERE clause` indicating the corresponding `user_id`, and the additional column will show `0` or `1`, depending that this `user_id` has a connection to each group or not.

Comment: can you clarify your question..are you wanting to providing a user_id in the where clause and the additional column is 0 or 1 if the provided user is in the group? or get a list of all groups, with a column of all users in the group?

Comment: @DerekDowney the former one. I added description to the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if that's what you are expecting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your updated question:

```
SELECT group_title, IF(user_id IS NULL, 0, 1)
FROM groups
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, group_id 
          FROM group_members WHERE user_id=1)gMembers USING(group_id)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9cfd7/11)